# Swap order of text using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm not sure how to describe what I'm asking in the title alone.

Ok so I have a HUGE list I'm entering into a SQL DB with a custom program. It imports the items from pastebin. However, I completely spaced how the info needed to be ordered.

So here is a small list example

```
M9; 15002
M9 Mag; 15101
FiveSeven; 15003
FiveSeven Mag; 15110
MP443; 15004
MP443 Mag; 15109
```

What I want to know if it's even possible is to have notepad++ take the text and make it like this

```
15002; M9; 
15101; M9 Mag; 
15003; FiveSeven; 
15110; FiveSeven Mag; 
15004; MP443; 
15109; MP443 Mag;
```

I can manually if need be remove the trailing extra ; at the end of each line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Notepad++ press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

- Find what: `(^.*); (.*?$)`
- Replace with: `\2; \1;`
- Check *Regular expression* option

```
Before                                       After
```

[image]
[image]

The trick is to use two capture groups via `( )` and access them with `\1` and `\2`. But in reversed order

Comment: And I <3 you :) worked perfectly thank you so much!!